# Publish data from MQTT topics to Google cloud pubsub topics

Tags: mqtt, google-cloud-pubsub, mosquitto

I am using paho.mqtt.client to read data from mqtt topic. Is there any way to publish data from multiple Mqtt topics to multiple Google Pubsub topics , i.e mqtt_topic in Mqtt -> gcp_topic in Google cloud pubsub?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, as it stands your question needs a lot of work before anybody can answer it. Please read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python then in order to send multiple messages to multiple topics using paho.mqtt you can use publish.multiple in python e.g.

```
msgs = [{'topic':"paho/test/multiple", 'payload':"multiple 1"},
        ("paho/test/multiple", "multiple 2", 0, False)]
publish.multiple(msgs, hostname="mqtt.eclipse.org")
```

for further information take a look at the official documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#multiple